Why does MPMediaLibrary keep sending warnings and error messages at Xcode's console?
Even if we check authorization we are getting warnings at Xcode's console.
They seems to be not effecting functionally.
MSVEntitlementUtilities - Process **** PID[6637] - Group: (null) - Entitlement: com.apple.accounts.appleaccount.fullaccess - Entitled: NO - Error: (null)
Attempted to register account monitor for types client is not authorized to access: {(
"com.apple.account.iTunesStore"
)}
when
let song = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.nowPlayingItem
has been executed.
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:

                print("Access granted")
               
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    
                    if let song = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
                        print("Now playing item: \(song.title ?? "Unknown")")
                        
                        if song.title != nil { s = (song.title!)  }
                        if song.albumArtist != nil {  a = (song.artist!) }
                      
               
                    } else {
                        print("No song is currently playing")
                    }
                    
                }
            case .denied, .restricted:
                print("Access denied or restricted")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Authorization status not determined")
            @unknown default:
                fatalError("Unknown authorization status")
            }


Any luck on this one?
